# Spring data getting records valid for given year (with fields fromDate, toDate)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, persistent

I am trying to use JPA repository to filter some records from DB.

I got an entity with fields:

```
@Column(name = "from_date", nullable = false)
private ZonedDateTime fromDate;

@Column(name = "to_date", nullable = true)
private ZonedDateTime toDate;
```

I need to select all the records taking place for given year (lats say 2018). 
The tricky part is: if 'from_date' is from 2017, but 'to_date' is ie. 2019, I want to include that record.

Could You please give me some idea, how to sort it out? Is it possible to get that with just one method?
If possible, I would like to use query methods.

At the moment, I invented method:

```
List<ManualCorrection> findByFromDateGreaterThanEqualAndFromDateLessThanAndToDateGreaterThanEqual(ZonedDateTime yearStart,ZonedDateTime yearEnd, ZonedDateTime yearStart2);
```

However this doesn't give me all the records I'm interested in.

Thanks for Your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should find all `ManualCorrection` entities that have a `toDate >= yearStart` and a `fromDate <= yearEnd` which seems to be what you are looking for.

```
 List<ManualCorrection> findByToDateGreaterThanEqualAndFromDateLessThanEqual(
     ZonedDateTime yearStart,
     ZonedDateTime yearEnd
 );
```

Comment: kindly explain your answer along with your code . It will help future reader as well.

Comment: I am sorry Jens - my mistake, I had a bug somewhere else. Your answer was perfectly fine from the beginning, thank You very much! I don't want to bother You again, but I am wondering if it is possible to extend that method, and treat 'null's' in field 'toDate' as "infinite" (never ends)? Simple solution like: findByToDateIsNullOrToDateGreaterThanEqualAndFromDateLessThanEqual doesn't sounds like solution. For now I just got another method for this kind of records, but I'm joining results anyway.

Comment: You could use a `@Query` annotation and some `( .... or x IS NULL)` to achieve that.